# How to increase the maximum connection limit of a Postgres docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

The [official Postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) provides easy ways to change some configuration properties (e.g. the `POSTGRES_USER` environment variable to set the root user name). However, there is nothing similar to set the maximum connection limit. How do you increase the maximum connection limit of a Postgres docker container?